# Telegram SendPoll via Python: can't parse options JSON

Tags: python-requests, telegram-bot

When I try to send a Poll to a chat I receive the following error:

```
{'ok': False, 'error_code': 400, 'description': "Bad Request: can't parse options JSON object"}
```

Regarding to https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendpoll the "options" have to be an array out of strings, which obviously doesn't work.

This is the script I built:

```
import json, requests

telegram_poll_url = 'https://api.telegram.org/botXXXX:YYYY/sendPoll'
telegram_poll_data = {'chat_id': XXXX, 'options':  ["5 Minuten", "10 Minuten"], 'question': "Wann bist hier?", 'is_anonymous': False}

response = requests.post(telegram_poll_url, telegram_poll_data).json()
print(response)
```

**Edit: This also doesnt work**

```
options = ["5 Minuten", "10 Minuten"]
telegram_poll_data = {
    'chat_id': -321158590, 
    'options':  options, 
    'question': "Wann bist du im FF Haus?", 
    'is_anonymous': False
}

response = requests.post(telegram_poll_url, telegram_poll_data).json()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse your options list to JSON.

## GET

```
options = ['bla', 'bla2', 'bla3']
uri = f'https://api.telegram.org/bot{_TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN}/sendPoll?chat_id={chat_id}&' \
      f'question={question}&options={json.dumps(options)}&type={type_}&correct_option_id={correct_option_id}' \
      f'&is_anonymous=false'
get(uri)
```

Comment: How would that look in the code? Regarding to JSON Validators my JSON String is valid?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem until I realized I was supposed to send serialized JSON data through the `json` `requests.post()` parameter instead of the default `data`:

```
requests.post(telegram_poll_url, json=telegram_poll_data)
```

This way it would actually use the `application/json` Content-Type and allow the API server to properly decode the [sendPoll](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendpoll) fields.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following

```
import json


options = ["5 Minuten", "10 Minuten"]
telegram_poll_data = {
    'chat_id': -321158590, 
    'options':  json.dumps(options), 
    'question': "Wann bist du im FF Haus?", 
    'is_anonymous': False
}

response = requests.post(telegram_poll_url, json=telegram_poll_data)
```

i.e. `json.dumps(options)`